# Iterate through parts of image in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

First thanks for all the answers I already got from this site.

I'm new to OpenCV and really enjoyind working with this amazing tool.
What I'm trying to build is an aplication that makes a stop motion sequence of what someone writes in a blank piece of paper as he is writing it. The tricky part is that I don't want to save an image with the writers hand in front of the text.

In the last two weeks I've been developing this application using Python and OpenCV 2.
Already took care of perspective changes and simple image adjustments to show only text (Thanks a lot for this blog: http://opencvpython.blogspot.com.br/ and it's sudoku solver example).
My latest achievement was to detect if a hand was in front of the image, I used cv2.threshold  and cv2.countNonZero to see if there was too much black pixels in the image, (I know it might fails sometimes but I works for now, does anyone got a better idea on how to approach this?) So basically if the writer removes his hand from the page, the image is saved and if his hand is over the page it doesn't save.

My next idea was to apply the same logic but for sections of the page, for example:

- starts with blank page, whole image is saved
- finishes writing a sentence in the left half of the page and hand rests on the right half of the page, new saved image would be the new left half merged with the old right half (since the hand was in the way)
- the same logic applies for upper and lower halfs
- later will expand this logic to a grid on the page, instead of just 4 parts

This is what I got so far, obviously not working since I'm having troubles with seeng the image as an array

```
p=2 #number of pieces accross page, starting with 2
w=width/p
h=height/p

new_img = []   #new image

for y in range(np.size(firstimage,0),h):
    for x in range(np.size(firstimage,1),w):
        old_part = firstimage[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        new_part = newimage[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        if (countBlackPixels(new_part) < int((countBlackPixels(old_part))*5 )):
            new_img = new_img + new_part
        else:
            new_img = new_img + old_part

new_img = new_img.astype(np.float32)
```

Can someone help me with how to do this iteration and build a new image with parts of others?

Thanks!

Comment: About hand detection method - consider detecting skin on image, it's easy to implement and there is a lot of examples. Usually it's based on colors in HSV model - google for "opencv skin detection hsv python".

Comment: Thanks very much! That seems promising!